# How to change clip-path with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change image clip with javascript (no jquery) but it seems i'm not doing it right.

Here's the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/y4j7bLge/1/

```
css:
clip-path: inset(20px 20px 20px 20px); // works

javascript:
el.style.clipPath = "inset(60px 60px 60px 60px);" // doesn't work
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remove the `;` at end of the value.

```
el.style.clipPath = "inset(60px 60px 60px 60px)" 
//                                 here ------^^-----
```

```js
var el = document.getElementById("someImg")

// doesn't work
el.style.clipPath = "inset(60px 60px 60px 60px);"
```

```css
#someImg {
  width: 332px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url(https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg);
  clip-path: inset(20px 20px 20px 20px);
}
```

```html
<div id="someImg" width="332px" height="300px">

</div>
```

Comment: Hehe, Thank you! :)

Comment: what should be the key for the webkit-clip-path? Because this property doesn't work on safari.